# plugin active error

Tags: plugins

hi i installed instagram auto poster on my website by it cant be activated because this error :

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/agahiir2/domains/talarwp.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/instagram-auto-poster/instagram-api/Instagram.php on line 132
```

but this error is not from plugin because i installed and activated on another website successfully without problem
just has error on my website
i deactived some plugins on my website but its still has problem also i checked functions.php on my theme several times and it seems good!!!
i really need to fix this problem and active this plugin please help me

Comment: Your host should be running PHP 5.4+ to use shorthand arrays.

Comment: @OmarSoliman i think you're right because my php version is 5.3 i told to host manager to upgrade php version

Comment: thx @OmarSoliman its ok now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Omar Soliman suggests,

> Your host should be running PHP 5.4+ to use shorthand arrays.